# JQuery dialog & dynamic data issue

Tags: jquery

i know it is possible to load data dynamically into jquery dialog like

```
(document).ready(function () {
        $('a#popup').live('click', function (e) {
            var page = $(this).attr("href")

            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 450,
                width: 'auto',
                title: "Edit Employee",
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () { $dialog.dialog('close'); }
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {

                    __doPostBack('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>', '');
                }
            });


            $dialog.dialog('open');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

so i just want to know when i am loading another page data into jquery dialog like

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
```

then how can i determine that data has been loaded into dialog?

basically i need to show a busy icon when data is loading and when i can determine programmatically that data is loaded and now it can be shown into dialog then i will stop showing busy icon and just show the actual data into dialog...i search google but found nothing similar....so i need advise and sample code. thanks

Comment: is the `page` on the same server, or a different server? Normally browsers don't like you snooping for data inside of an `iframe`

Comment: Have you thought about using AJAX loading instead of an iframe? `.load()` has a callback function that will only fire after the URL is loaded and place into the page. (Won't work on URLs from other domains, though.)

Comment: i want to work with iframe...due to some situation i can not change the existing code....so guide me how to determine that data loading completed into iframe or not?

Comment: yes page is in the same server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function. You just add the function with a callback to the element you are waiting to be loaded.

Comment: i want to work with iframe...due to some situation i can not change the existing code....so guide me how to determine that data loading completed into iframe or not?